# d3.js Line chart won't show. Error 404 on console

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, d3.js

I'm new to d3.js and currently learning how to draw the line chart with a JSON data from my database. The problem is i can't show them. Please see the screenshot of the error below:
[image: console error]

This is my JSON data from my url
[image: JSON result]

As you can see, there is no problem on accessing the JSON on my URL(`http://localhost:9090/perHourAvailabilities/2020-04-15`).
But when i tried converting them to my chart, i can't show them. I don't know if the problem is with my JSON or my chart since i can't show them and the error i kept getting is error 404. I'm using also Java Spring for my project.

This is my code for my chart:

```
 /* START OF LINE CHART */
$(document).ready(() => {
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // parse the date / time
    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");

    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    // define the line
    var valueline = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.availability_time); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d.total_hour_percentage); });
    // define the line

    // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select("#lineChart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    function draw(data) {
        //console.log(data);

        // format the data
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.availability_time = +d.availability_time;
            d.total_hour_percentage = +d.total_hour_percentage;
        });

        // sort time ascending
        data.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a["availability_time"] - b["availability_time"];
        })

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.availability_time;
        }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return Math.max(d.total_up_percentage);
        })]);

        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline);
        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    }
    // Get the data
    var perHourResult = "/perHourAvailabilities/" + defaultDate;
    console.log(perHourResult);

    d3.json(perHourResult)
        .then((data) => {
            // console.log(data.length);

            //console.log(data[0].Date)
            // d3.select("#selectButton")
            //     .selectAll("myOptions")
            //     .data(data)
            //     .enter()
            //     .append("option")
            //     .text((d) => {
            //         return d.Date;
            //     })
            //     .attr("value", (d) => {
            //         return d.Date;
            //     })
            //console.log(data[i].Date);

            draw(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
enter code here
```

======================= UPDATE ==============================
An error is found on the  variable:
[image: path error]

it seems that this is what causing the error. Because it's expecting me to return a number but on my JSON query result `availability_time` is a `timestamp` element. Is there a way to make it a string or fix the error on the `<path>`?
Also when I access the `(data)` on my console: it shows this:
[image: NaN error]

===============UPDATE_2========================
Fixed the error on the time being NaN on the console. It seems that this is the error:

```
data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.availability_time = +d.availability_time;
        d.total_hour_percentage = +d.total_hour_percentage;
    });
```

it should have been:

```
data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.availability_time = d.availability_time;
        d.total_hour_percentage = +d.total_hour_percentage;
    });
```

but the error on the `<path>` still persist. It seems that it's expecting a number on the `availability_time`

Comment: Your d3 script also runs on port 9090 right? What happens if you pass the complete url to d3.json?

Comment: The error is still the same. Will update the question since i saw a new problem.